# Should Specification Patterns return IEnumerable, IQueryable, or Expression?

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design, software, .net-core

We are implementing Specification Patterns with Domain Driven Design. Company architect also wants us to utilize Generic repository (not my choice).  Currently require specification Pattern for Filter Where, Sorting, and Paging- 3 different ones.

Are specification patterns supposed to return IEnumerable, IQueryable, or Expression? Or does it matter? If we have separate classes for filter, page, and sort, which can be combined in any manner, shouldn't they be Iqueryable ? Just need recommendations for this.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The [Specification Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) description does IMHO not mention return values for which IEnumerable, IQueryable, or Expression are suitable. So could you give a more detailed example, maybe some pseudocode, of what you have in mind? (Voting to close as "unclear" until you fix this).

Comment: A specification is, on the surface, just something you pass as a parameter to a query. So return whatever type you'd return if you weren't using specifications. What you should do is get all of the involved devs and architects together and just have a quick session where you will check if you have different conceptual views of this, and then iron that out - define and reach an agreement on what is meant by specification pattern, how it should manifest itself in this particular project, and how it should all work and fit together.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with [Microsoft's documentation for IQueryable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=netframework-4.8).  It says:

> The `IQueryable` interface inherits the `IEnumerable` interface so that if it represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated. Enumeration causes the expression tree associated with an `IQueryable` object to be executed. The definition of "executing an expression tree" is specific to a query provider. For example, it may involve translating the expression tree to an appropriate query language for the underlying data source.

In other words, an `IEnumerable` represents a collection that can be enumerated, while an `IQueryable` represents some sort of query that can be executed.  Think of `IQueryable` as a "state machine" of sorts; it doesn't actually do anything until you compel it to execute by calling `ToList()` or something that enumerates its output.  So you can build up an `IQueryable` with successive Linq statements, and nothing will happen until you actually ask it for output.

I was looking over the C# version of the Specification Pattern on Wikipedia.  It's hilariously verbose, given that all you really need is some lambda expressions:

```
var licenseHasNotExpired = license => license.ExpiryDate > DateTime.Now;
```

You can use [Joseph Albahari's Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to chain together your lambda expressions with AND and OR, and presto: you have a Specification Pattern.  You can use it to build up an expression tree that gets executed when you need the answer to the questions that your rules answer.

If you use Expression Trees to do this, you can even [run a Visitor over them to get log output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34047715/102937).

Comment: Verbose indeed. Lambda expressions are backed internally by the LINQ Expression classes which seem to implement pretty much just that: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions?view=netstandard-2.0